# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Descendant')

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, dockerfile

I have a React.js application which I have a Dockerfile and both the app and the Dockerfile worked fine until today when I tried to build the docker file and I got the exception form the title.

This exception is triggered after the `npm run build` command in the Dockerfile. I tried the same command locally for my project and there was no problem. It happens only in the Dockerfile when I try to build it with `docker build -t image .`

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.13.0 as build

RUN  apt-get update -y && apt-get install mosquitto-clients -y

# Creates scripts to publish update messages and give system permission to read it
RUN echo "mosquitto_pub -t watchtower/update/dashboard -h mosquitto -p 1883 -m "{status: checking, service: Dashboard}"" > pre-check.sh && chmod +rx pre-check.sh 
RUN echo "mosquitto_pub -t watchtower/update/dashboard -h mosquitto -p 1883 -m "{status: updating, service: Dashboard}"" > pre-update.sh && chmod +rx pre-update.sh   
RUN echo "mosquitto_pub -t watchtower/update/dashboard -h mosquitto -p 1883 -m "{status: updated, service: Dashboard}"" > post-update.sh && chmod +rx post-update.sh 
RUN echo "mosquitto_pub -t watchtower/update/dashboard -h mosquitto -p 1883 -m "{status: checked, service: Dashboard}"" > post-check.sh && chmod +rx post-check.sh

# Connect watchtower hook to the above created script
LABEL com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.lifecycle.pre-check="/pre-check.sh"
LABEL com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.lifecycle.pre-update="/pre-update.sh"
LABEL com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.lifecycle.post-update="/post-update.sh"
LABEL com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.lifecycle.post-check="/post-check.sh"

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY /front-end/package.json /app

RUN npm install

COPY ./front-end/ /app

RUN npm run build

# Install `serve` to run the application.
RUN npm install -g serve

# Set the command to start the node server.
CMD serve -s build

# Tell Docker about the port we'll run on.
EXPOSE 5000
```

Any idea how to resolve that issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure you're using the save version of node and npm locally vs in the container? are you sure your installed packages are the same? remove your local node_modules, run `npm install` again and see if you still get no error locally on `npm run build`.

Comment: to me it seems like a package version mismatch of some sort. but you'll need to provide more info, i.e. which package & file the error is originating from, and what is the object that is trying to read `Descendant` property.

Comment: For me, the problem was that the version of node I was using as a base image (v12) was older than my locally installed node (v18). This created a mismatch between the package specified by the app and the package available to node inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

Just got this on a vite app, nuking the `node_modules` dir and `npm install` worked for me!

Comment: This happened with a nuxt 2 project. Removing the `node_modules` directory was the fix.